# How to fix spacing feature in Zeplin" It shows: "NaNpx" instead of exact px values

Tags: zeplin

I exported screen from Adobe XD to Zeplin. In a result Zeplin do not show measurement of spacing between elements. It shows: "NaNpx" instead of exact values. Does anyone could give me a hint how to solve this?

[Example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEIri.png)

ADDED:

I tried to make it as simple as it can be: 
I created a new blank project in Adobe XD. Draw a square.By holding 'alt' key I can see measurement of spacing. Now I exported the screen to Zeplin. Measurements are not visible. Attached print screens

[Situation in ADOBE XD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soIC2.png) and 
[Situation in Zeplin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYLtA.png)

Comment: `NaN` stands for "not a number". You need to trace back to where something that isn't a number (which could be a blank space) got put in there.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for a hint. I didn't know what should I trace back to find a cause of a problem, threfore tried to make it simpled. Created a blank project, draw a simple square and exported to Zeplin. Still the same issue. I have added print screens above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear Maciej Śmigaj,

I faced the same problem and it solved automatically when i restarted the operating system, i hope this works for you too.

Good Luck